# Java Error: int cannot be dereferenced

Tags: java

I'm writing a simple Java program to do a temperature conversion, and I keep getting an error on line 8 (which I have marked in the code below) that the int cannot be dereferenced.  I'm not sure exactly what this means, or how to fix it, and other questions here with the same error did not help with finding a solution for my error.

```
import java.util.*;

class TemperatureConversion { 

        public TemperatureConversion()
        {
            int x = 0;
            x.getInput.Int("Would you like to convert from Fahrenheit to Celcius or Celcius to Fahrenheit? Enter '1' for Fahrenheit to Celcius, and 2 for Celsius to Fahrenheit.");  //This is the line with the error

            if(x == 1)
            {
                toCelsius();
            }
            if(x ==2)
            {
                toFahrenheit();
            }
        }


        public void toCelsius()
        {
                double fahrenheit = 0.0;    
                fahrenheit = Input.getDouble("Enter the temperature in Fahrenheit to be converted to Celsius.");
                System.out.println("The converted value is " + (5.0/9.0 * (fahrenheit + 32)) + " degrees Celsius.");
        }

        public void toFahrenheit()
        {
                double celsius = 0.0;
                celsius = Input.getDouble("Enter the temperature in Celsius to be converted to Fahrenheit.");
                System.out.println("The converted value is " + (9.0/5.0 * (celsius + 32)) + " degrees Fahrenheit."); 
        }
```

}

Comment: I would like to know where you got the idea to write this `x.getInput.Int(` or `fahrenheit = Input.getDouble(`.  Neither of these are using standard Java APIs.  Do you have some source on the internet that is telling you to write this stuff?  Are you looking at code written in a different programming language?

Comment: @Stephen C, I'm taking a class and my teacher said in the instructions to get user input using that method.  Usually I use a scanner, and I understand that that's a much better way to do something like this.

Comment: @Claire - it seems that either the instructor's instructions are unclear or you are misinterpreting them.  Certainly in the first case.  (The second case is plausible ... if the instructor has provided you with something that defines the `Input` class.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

x is an `int`, a primitive, and therefore cannot be dereferenced - meaning x.anything is invalid syntax in Java.

I'm assuming what you meant to do is assign some user input to x :

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int x = sc.nextInt();
```